# Golang net package mocking

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I'm trying to learn to write tests in golang on a personal project of mine.

Bunch of the functions in my project are using `net` package, however since I'm new to this I don't know how to mock the functions from packages such as `net` one which are interacting with the host's devices.

To make my question more concrete, I have a function similar to this:

```
func NewThingy(ifcName string) (*Thingy, error) {
    if ifc, err := net.InterfaceByName(ifcName); err == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Interface name %s already assigned on the host", ifcName)
    }

    ....

    return &Thingy{
        ifc: ifc,
    }, nil
}
```

Thingy is clearly defined as:

```
type Thingy struct {
  ifc *net.Interface
}
```

Anyone could give me any hints how to go about testing code like this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is that you can't mock things like that. Go is a statically compiled language, so unlike ruby or other dynamic languages, there is no support for magically rewriting fixed function calls on the fly.

If you really want to test it, you have two obvious options:

- Define `NewThingy` to take a function pointer whose type matches `net.InterfaceByName`. Pass that function to all "real" calls to the function, but pass a dummy function pointer in your tests. This will slightly slow down the code however, and isn't pleasant to read or write.
- Require your test environment to use legitimate data. May or may not be possible depending on your requirements, but there are some packages that may help (I wrote https://github.com/eapache/peroxide for a similar purpose, but it doesn't deal with interfaces so it's probably not what you're looking for).

Comment: Yeah I figured it's probably not easy. I read some blog posts like http://nathany.com/go-testing-toolbox/ which do suggest point 1 i.e. dependency injection, but that would require total refactoring of my code. I can not find anything useful for my use case. Your package is for testing network services. I need to mock creating and destroying devices etc.

Comment: Dependency injection is what is described in the first bullet. It's definitely the idiomatic way to write Go code (and all other object oriented code). Here's a simplified version: http://play.golang.org/p/oBjtKqGShX

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but [Gomock](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/gomock/gomock) provides for mocking by generating code for whatever interface you give it. To use it, you need to use an interface-based coding style, rather than relying directly on structs.

Because many of the standard library packages use interfaces, mocking them with Gomock is effective. For any that don't, you might need to write an (untested) shim that provides the necessary interface layer. This seems less messy to me than the idea of passing function pointers to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Looks like net.Interface is tested by shelling out into actual ip command http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/interface_linux_test.go

Comment: gyre: Whoa, it didn’t occur to me that I could look at the actual library tests. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and ended up using this package to mock:
https://github.com/foxcpp/go-mockdns

```
srv, _ := mockdns.NewServer(map[string]mockdns.Zone{
    "example.org.": {
        A: []string{"1.2.3.4"},
    },
}, false)
defer srv.Close()

srv.PatchNet(net.DefaultResolver)
defer mockdns.UnpatchNet(net.DefaultResolver)

addrs, err := net.LookupHost("example.org")
fmt.Println(addrs, err)
```

it also has an option to create a mock resolver object but then you have to use dependency injection to inject the mock resolver to be used internally:

```
r := mockdns.Resolver{
    Zones: map[string]mockdns.Zone{
        "example.org.": {
            A: []string{"1.2.3.4"},
        },
    },
}

addrs, err := r.LookupHost(context.Background(), "example.org")
fmt.Println(addrs, err)
```